# MYSQL: calculating age with year from 2 cloumn

Tags: mysql, constraints, date-arithmetic

I have the DateofBirth column and YearJoined column in a table. 
DateofBith is integer while YearJoined input uses Year(Now()).
How do I compare the year from the 2 column and check the age of the person that joins the club is above 18?

Comment: Can you please show some data from these two fields

Answer (score 0):

Following query will help for this issue, I guess,

```
DECLARE @dob  datetime

SET @dob='1992-01-09 00:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766.0 AS AgeYearsDecimal
    ,CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS AgeYearsIntRound
    ,DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
```

Hope you get the answer..